# Tensorflow: Logistic regression cost=NaN

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a logistic regression problem having 9 different targets. When debugging I get

`Epoch: 0025 cost= nan`

This is how one batch looks like

**batch_xs**

```
[[  3.40000000e+01   3.34000000e+01   9.00000000e-02   3.40000000e+01
    4.06858908e+00   0.00000000e+00   3.30000000e+01   4.04000000e+01
    1.00000000e-02   3.30000000e+01   4.06858908e+00   1.00000000e+00
    3.20000000e+01   4.22000000e+01   7.00000000e-01   3.20000000e+01
    4.06858908e+00   2.00000000e+00   3.10000000e+01   4.18000000e+01
    5.00000000e-01   3.10000000e+01   4.06858908e+00   3.00000000e+00
    3.00000000e+01   3.70000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+01
    4.06858908e+00   4.00000000e+00   2.90000000e+01   3.78000000e+01
    2.00000000e-02   2.90000000e+01   4.06858908e+00   5.00000000e+00
    2.80000000e+01   3.78000000e+01   2.00000000e-02   2.90000000e+01
    4.06858908e+00   6.00000000e+00   4.90000000e+01   4.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e+00]]
```

**batch_ys:**

```
[[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

While the originnal y was. I converted it into a (_,9) matrix using convert_y

```
[[3]]
```

This is some of the code I use

```
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 25
batch_size = 1
display_step = 1

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,feature_column_count])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,n_target_classes])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([feature_column_count,n_target_classes]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_target_classes]))

pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

def next_batch(num, data, labels):
    idx = np.arange(0, len(data))
    idx = idx[:num]
    data_s = data[idx]
    labels_s = labels[idx]

    return np.asarray(data_s), np.asarray(labels_s)

def convert_y(size,n_classes,y):
    yk = np.zeros((size,n_classes), dtype=np.int)

    for a in range(len(y)):
        yk[a,y[a]] = 1

    return yk


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(np.shape(TRAINING_SET.data)[0]/batch_size)

        for i in range(total_batch):
            features = TRAINING_SET.data
            target = TRAINING_SET.target

            batch_xs,batch_ys = next_batch(batch_size, features, target)
            batch_ys = convert_y(len(batch_ys),n_target_classes,batch_ys)

            print(batch_xs)
            print(batch_ys)

            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})

            avg_cost += c / total_batch

        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    print("Test Accuracy:",accuracy.eval({x: TRAINING_SET.data, y: convert_y(len(TRAINING_SET.target),n_target_classes,TRAINING_SET.target)}))
    print("Validation Accuracy:",accuracy.eval({x: VALIDATION_SET.data, y: convert_y(len(VALIDATION_SET.target),n_target_classes,VALIDATION_SET.target)}))
```

Anyone knows where the code issue is?

Comment: You can use [`tf.verify_tensor_all_finite`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/verify_tensor_all_finite) after different steps to find out where is the first `NaN` in the graph. In this case I _think_ the problem is that you are initializing all your variables with zeros instead of using some kind of [random initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027598/why-should-weights-of-neural-networks-be-initialized-to-random-numbers).

Comment: thanks. will try verify_tensor_all_finite. I think random initialisation is only required for neural networks. what I didn't do is feature scaling. will try that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

For regression it's better to use mean_square loss. you may try the following.
Also gradient clipping would help

```
logits = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, logits)))
learning_rate = 0.01
momentum = 0.9
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, momentum,  use_nesterov=True)
grads_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
cliped_grads_vars = []
for gard, var in grads_vars:
    grad = tf.clip_by_norm(grad, max_norm=10.0)
    clipped_grads_vars.append((gard, var))
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(clipped_gards_vars)
....

_, c = sess.run([train_op, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})
```