# Initial weights in Network with Keras / Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to get the initial weights for a given network.

This thread suggests that one needs to specify the input dimension: [How to view initialized weights (i.e. before training)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798708/how-to-view-initialized-weights-i-e-before-training)

This thread suggests that after compilation weights should be available: [Reset weights in Keras layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496069/reset-weights-in-keras-layer)

> Save the initial weights right after compiling the model but before training it.

While I reproduced the results in the first post I am unable to apply it to my case:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf

# Reproducing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798708/how-to-view-initialized-weights-i-e-before-training

# First model without input_dim prints an empty list
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, weights=[np.ones((3, 5)), np.zeros(5)],
                activation='relu'))
print(model.get_weights())

# Second model with input_dim prints the assigned weights
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(5, weights=[np.ones((3, 5)), np.zeros(5)],
                 input_dim=3,
                 activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

print(model1.get_weights())


class Test(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs: int, neurons=10):
        super(Test, self).__init__(name="Test")
        self.neurons = neurons

        # Initilializers
        mean, std = 0., 0.0005
        bias_normalization = None
        kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=mean,
                                                                stddev=std)
        self.h1 = Dense(n_inputs, activation="linear", name="h1",
                        kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                        bias_initializer=bias_normalization,
                        input_dim=n_inputs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.h1(inputs)
        return x


# Model Test

test = Test(n_inputs=1, neurons=100)
test.get_weights()  # empty, expected

test.compile()
test.get_weights()  # empty, unexpected
```

Comment: what's the issue with the second suggestion? To save the weights immediatelly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I think it all depends on when the `call` method of `tf.keras.Model` is actually called. Also, Keras sequential models and subclassing models behave differently.

Your model's weights are only created when you pass real data or explicitly call `build(*)`. For example, if you try the following you will get an output of some weights:

```
test_model = Test(n_inputs=1, neurons=100)
test_model(np.random.random((32, 1)))
print(test_model.get_weights())
# [array([[0.00057544]]), array([0.3752869])]
```

or

```
test_model.build(input_shape=(32, 1))
print(test_model.get_weights())
# [array([[8.942684e-05]], dtype=float32), array([-1.6799461], dtype=float32)]
```

Basically, the `call` method internally calls the `__call__` method. If you check out the official Tensorflow [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#call) you can read about this behavior:

> To call a model on an input, always use the **call** method, i.e. model(inputs), which relies on the underlying call method.

You could by the way also define your `Test` class as follows:

```py
class Test(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs: int, neurons=10):
        super(Test, self).__init__(name="Test")
        self.neurons = neurons

        # Initilializers
        mean, std = 0., 0.0005
        bias_normalization = None
        kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=mean,
                                                           stddev=std)
        model_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_inputs,))
        x= tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_inputs, activation="linear", name="h1",
                        kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                        bias_initializer=bias_normalization)(model_input)
        self.model = tf.keras.Model(model_input, x)
```

```
test_model = Test(n_inputs=1, neurons=100)
print(test_model.get_weights())
# [array([[0.00045629]], dtype=float32), array([0.9945322], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: Thank you. When subclassing, is there a way to build the model without explicitly using Model? Why does the following not work?  Adding input = Input(shape=(n_inputs, ))
        self.h1 = Dense(n_inputs, activation="linear", name="h1",
                        kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                        bias_initializer=bias_normalization,
                        input_shape=(n_inputs,))
And then calling compile(). Does that not build the model? Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I haven’t ever tried this option

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you choose the burden to define a specific class here, but your `Test` class does not define a model, only a single `Dense` layer; hence, it is not strange that you do not end up with any weights whatsoever. Changing `self.h1` to:

```
        self.h1 = Sequential(Dense(n_inputs, activation="linear", name="h1",
                        kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                        bias_initializer=bias_normalization,
                        input_dim=n_inputs))
```

will do the trick in both cases:

```
test = Test(n_inputs=1, neurons=100)
test.get_weights()  
# [array([[-0.00030265]], dtype=float32), array([-1.6327941], dtype=float32)]

test.compile()
test.get_weights()  # same weights as above
# [array([[-0.00030265]], dtype=float32), array([-1.6327941], dtype=float32)]
```

Notice that there seem to be changes in different versions, as the frameworks evolve, so some details from old threads might be different today. For example, in the Keras version currently used in Google Colab (2.6.0), `model.get_weights()` will throw an error if `input_dim` is not defined - it will *not* return an empty list:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
import keras

keras.__version__
# '2.6.0'

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, weights=[np.ones((3, 5)), np.zeros(5)],
                activation='relu'))
print(model.get_weights())
```

This gives:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-1f22e9c3ce78> in <module>()
      2 model.add(Dense(5, weights=[np.ones((3, 5)), np.zeros(5)],
      3                 activation='relu'))
----> 4 print(model.get_weights())

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in get_weights(self)
   2090     """
   2091     with self.distribute_strategy.scope():
-> 2092       return super(Model, self).get_weights()
   2093 
   2094   def save(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in get_weights(self)
   1844         Weights values as a list of NumPy arrays.
   1845     """
-> 1846     weights = self.weights
   1847     output_weights = []
   1848     for weight in weights:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in weights(self)
   2488       A list of variables.
   2489     """
-> 2490     return self._dedup_weights(self._undeduplicated_weights)
   2491 
   2492   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _undeduplicated_weights(self)
   2493   def _undeduplicated_weights(self):
   2494     """Returns the undeduplicated list of all layer variables/weights."""
-> 2495     self._assert_weights_created()
   2496     weights = []
   2497     for layer in self._self_tracked_trackables:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in _assert_weights_created(self)
    465     # When the graph has not been initialized, use the Model's implementation to
    466     # to check if the weights has been created.
--> 467     super(functional.Functional, self)._assert_weights_created()  # pylint: disable=bad-super-call
    468 
    469 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _assert_weights_created(self)
   2672                        'Weights are created when the Model is first called on '
   2673                        'inputs or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`.' %
-> 2674                        self.name)
   2675 
   2676   def _check_call_args(self, method_name):

ValueError: Weights for model sequential_1 have not yet been created. Weights are created when the Model is first called on inputs or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`.
```

Finally, as a general remark, you should be careful *not* to mix functionality from `keras` and `tf.keras`; these are different libraries, so choose one and stick to it consistently throughout your code.

Comment: Thank you. Still very green on this. The reason for subclassing is because I inherited the code from another source. The class itself would build a multi-output model, but one should be able to create the model through Functional API without need for subclassing. For same reasons above I had not noticed the usage of different libraries. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: When you say it doesn't define a model, can you clarify? The Sequential is also inherited from Model. This will give a true: assert isinstance(test, tf.keras.Model)