# Why does this neural network learn nothing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am learning TensorFlow and was implementing a simple neural network as explained in MNIST for Beginners in TensorFlow docs. Here is the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners). The accuracy was about 80-90 %, as expected.

Then following the same article was MNIST for Experts using ConvNet. Instead of implementing that I decided to improve the beginner part. I know about Neural Nets and how they learn and the fact that deep networks can perform better than shallow networks. I modified the original program in MNIST for Beginner to implement a Neural network with 2 hidden layers each of 16 neurons.

It looks something like this :

## Image of Network

[image: the neural network i build]

## Code for it

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], 'images')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], 'labels')

# We are going to make 2 hidden layer neurons with 16 neurons each

# All the weights in network
W0 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='InputLayerWeights', initial_value=tf.zeros([784, 16]))
W1 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='HiddenLayer1Weights', initial_value=tf.zeros([16, 16]))
W2 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='HiddenLayer2Weights', initial_value=tf.zeros([16, 10]))

# All the biases for the network
B0 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='HiddenLayer1Biases', initial_value=tf.zeros([16]))
B1 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='HiddenLayer2Biases', initial_value=tf.zeros([16]))
B2 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='OutputLayerBiases', initial_value=tf.zeros([10]))


def build_graph():
    """This functions wires up all the biases and weights of the network
    and returns the last layer connections
    :return: returns the activation in last layer of network/output layer without softmax
    """
    A1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W0) + B0)
    A2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(A1, W1) + B1)
    return tf.matmul(A2, W2) + B2


def print_accuracy(sx, sy, tf_session):
    """This function prints the accuracy of a model at the time of invocation
    :return: None
    """
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y), tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(build_graph())))
    correct_prediction_float = tf.cast(correct_prediction, dtype=tf.float32)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction_float)

    print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: sx, y: sy}, session=tf_session))


y_predicted = build_graph()

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=y_predicted))

model = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.03).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(1000):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if _ % 100 == 0:
            print_accuracy(batch_x, batch_y, sess)
        sess.run(model, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

The Output expected was supposed to be better than what could be achieved with when just a single layer (Assumed that W0 has shape of [784,10] and B0 has shape of [10])

```
def build_graph():
     return tf.matmul(x,W0) + B0
```

Instead, the output says that network was not training at all. The Accuracy was not crossing 20% in any iteration.

## Output

> Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
>
> Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
>
> Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
>
> Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
>
> 0.1
>
> 0.1
>
> 0.1
>
> 0.1
>
> 0.1
>
> 0.1
>
> 0.1
>
> 0.1
>
> 0.1
>
> 0.1

## My Question

What is wrong with the above program that it does not generalize at all? How can I improve it more without using convolutional neural networks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main mistake is [network symmetry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20027598/712995), because you initialized *all* weights to zeros. As a result, the weights are never updated. Change it to small random numbers and it will start learning. It's ok to initialize biases with zeros.

Another issue is pure technical: `print_accuracy` function is creating new nodes in the computational graph, and since you're calling it in the loop, the graph gets bloated and eventually will use up all memory.

You might also want to play with hyper-parameters and make the network bigger to increase its capacity.

**Edit:** I also spotted a bug in your accuracy calculation. It should be

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_predicted, 1))
```

Here's a complete code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], 'images')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], 'labels')

W0 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='InputLayerWeights', initial_value=tf.truncated_normal([784, 16]) * 0.001)
W1 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='HiddenLayer1Weights', initial_value=tf.truncated_normal([16, 16]) * 0.001)
W2 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='HiddenLayer2Weights', initial_value=tf.truncated_normal([16, 10]) * 0.001)

B0 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='HiddenLayer1Biases', initial_value=tf.ones([16]))
B1 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='HiddenLayer2Biases', initial_value=tf.ones([16]))
B2 = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='OutputLayerBiases', initial_value=tf.ones([10]))

A1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W0) + B0)
A2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(A1, W1) + B1)
y_predicted = tf.matmul(A2, W2) + B2
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_predicted, 1))
correct_prediction_float = tf.cast(correct_prediction, dtype=tf.float32)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction_float)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=y_predicted))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('mnist', one_hot=True)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for i in range(20000):
    batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(64)
    _, cost_val, acc_val = sess.run([optimizer, cross_entropy, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
    if i % 100 == 0:
      print('cost=%.3f accuracy=%.3f' % (cost_val, acc_val))
```

Comment: Yes I found that bug and fixed that bug of tf.argmax(y,1). Let me check your program and see if it works. Also I would like to ask why initialization of wights to zero in case no no hidden layer works? And same does not work in multilayer as this