# How does TensorFlow train kernels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, convolution

TensorFlow's API describes the function `tf.nn.conv2d()` which takes in an argument of filter size: `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channel, out_channel]`. So if I used the mnist dataset and ran the network on an image displaying the number "5," would the filter be trained on the lower, circular bowl of the 5? Or would it just train on multiple parts of the image? How and what would the filters in the conv2d train on?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the basic principles of [convolutional layers](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv):

> Every filter is small spatially (along width and height), but extends through the full depth of the input volume. For example, a typical filter on a first layer of a ConvNet might have size `5x5x3` (i.e. 5 pixels width and height, and 3 because images have depth 3, the color channels).
>
> During the forward pass, we slide (more precisely, convolve) each filter across the width and height of the input volume and compute dot products between the entries of the filter and the input at any position. As we slide the filter over the width and height of the input volume we will produce a 2-dimensional activation map that gives the responses of that filter at every spatial position.
>
> Intuitively, the network will learn filters that activate when they see some type of visual feature such as an edge of some orientation or a blotch of some color on the first layer, or eventually entire honeycomb or wheel-like patterns on higher layers of the network. Now, we will have an entire set of filters in each CONV layer (e.g. 12 filters), and each of them will produce a separate 2-dimensional activation map. We will stack these activation maps along the depth dimension and produce the output volume.

So, in essence, each `[filter_height, filter_width]` filter is going to match *all patches* of the same size in the input and produce a single number for each patch. Some patches can be skipped or added, depending on the `stride` and `padding` settings. In the backward pass, the filter will be updated for all of them, i.e., it is trained on the *whole input*.

E.g., here's `stride=1` and `padding=2` convolution:

[image: conv]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but to confirm, you're saying, conclusively, that the kernels will learn unique features by themselves?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "by themselves". The ground truth label is provided to CNN. Using this label the delta is calculated and backpropagated to all layers, conv kernels in particular, so that they learn that certain patterns help in prediction.

Comment: So does this garuntee that each kernel passing over the image is unique? I mean could there be cases where you'd have kernels that filter the exact same features?

Comment: I see your point. See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103096/712995