# Why filters do not learn same features

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

The result of the convolution operation is multiple subsets of data are generated per kernel. For example if 5 kernels are applies to an image of dimension WxDx1 (1 channel) then 5 convolutions are applied to the data which generates a 5 dimensional image representation. WxDx1 becomes W'xD'x5 where W' and D' are smaller in dimension that W * D

Is the fact that each kernel is initialised to different values prevent each kernel from learning the same parameters ? If not what prevents each kernel learning the same parameters ?

If the image is RGB instead of grayscale so dimension WxDx3 instead of WxDx1 does this impact how the kernels learns patterns ?

Comment: The kernels are the learnable parameters in convolution, so yes, they do learn.

Comment: oh yes my bad! made a confusion, sorry, weight ARE indeed the kernels parameters. sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned, the sole fact of differing *what* Kernels learn is due to the random initialization of the weights in the beginning.

A great explanation is delivered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027598/why-should-weights-of-neural-networks-be-initialized-to-random-numbers) and also applies for the convolutional kernels in CNNs. 
I regard this as distinct enough to not highlight it as a duplicate, but essentially it works the same.