# LSTM only train once using keras

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to train a LSTM model to predict the temperature.but the model only got trained in first epochs.

I got the usage and temperature of cpu from a server in about twenty hours as the dataset.I want to predict the temperature of cpu after 10m by using 10m's data before.so I reshape my dataset to (1301,10,2) as I have 1301 samples,10m timesteps and 2 features, then I divide it to 1201 and 100 as the train dataset and the validation dataset.

I check the dataset manually,so it should be right.

I creat the LSTM model as below

```py
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(10, activation="relu", input_shape=(train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2]),return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='RMSprop')
```

and try to fit it

```py
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_data=(test_x, test_y), verbose=2)
```

I got the log like this:

```
Epoch 1/50
 - 1s - loss: 0.8016 - val_loss: 0.8147
Epoch 2/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.8016 - val_loss: 0.8147
Epoch 3/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.8016 - val_loss: 0.8147
Epoch 4/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.8016 - val_loss: 0.8147
Epoch 5/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.8016 - val_loss: 0.8147
Epoch 6/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.8016 - val_loss: 0.8147
Epoch 7/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.8016 - val_loss: 0.8147
Epoch 8/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.8016 - val_loss: 0.8147
Epoch 9/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.8016 - val_loss: 0.8147
```

The trainning time of each epoch is 0 expect the first epoch,and the loss never decrease.I tried changing the number of LSTM cells,loss function and optimizer,but it still don't work.

Comment: The key to the problem is that the unit number of your last layer is 1. The result of 'tf.nn.softmax' are all the same .You can refer [Neural Network with Tensorflow doesn't update weights/bias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55214395/neural-network-with-tensorflow-doesnt-update-weights-bias/55215362#55215362)

Comment: Try using sigmoid activation in the last layer

Comment: changing to sigmoid works.Thank you both very much!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the activation function of last layer from softmax to sigmoid make the model works.Thanks to @giser_yugang @Ashwin Geet D'Sa